# Getting isEqualToString: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, memory-management

I'm getting this error when clicking the same UIButton twice, it crashes the second time only when the request to the server is not able to go through.

`-[SendHelloFax isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12b49150`

Update:  I used breakpoints and found that the line it is crashing at is:

```
    if (!errorMessage || [errorMessage isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
        errorMessage = @"Failed to send fax. Please check your WiFi or 3G connection and try again.";
    }
```

Methods:

```
- (IBAction)sendFaxButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *errorMessage;
    int rcode = [MyDataSource sendFax:self.appointment phone_call_id:self.phone_call_id document_url:self.document_url targetId:self.contact_id targetName:self.name.text targetNumber:self.faxNumber.text coverSheetMessage:self.coverSheetMessage.text errorMessage:&errorMessage];

    if (rcode) {
        if (!errorMessage || [errorMessage isEqualToString:@""]) {
            errorMessage = @"Failed to send fax. Please check your WiFi or 3G connection and try again.";
        }

        UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error" message:errorMessage delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [someError show];
        [someError release];
        return;
    }

    if (!rcode) {   
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
    }
}

+(int)sendFax:(int)appointment_id phone_call_id:(int)phone_call_id document_url:(NSString*)document_url targetId:(int)contactId targetName:(NSString*)targetName targetNumber:(NSString*)targetNumber coverSheetMessage:(NSString*)coverSheetMessage errorMessage:(NSString**)errorMessage
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ichrono/20110715/60b88126/fax_send/", [self getMyHost]]];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [self addCurrentUserLoginToPostRequest:request];        

    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", contactId] forKey:@"fax_contact_id"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", appointment_id] forKey:@"appointment_id"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", phone_call_id] forKey:@"phone_call_id"];

    [request setPostValue:document_url forKey:@"url_to_fax"];
    [request setPostValue:targetNumber forKey:@"fax_number"];
    [request setPostValue:targetName forKey:@"full_name"];
    [request setPostValue:coverSheetMessage forKey:@"coversheet_message"];


    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSString *responseString;
    if (!error) {
        responseString = [request responseString];
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [responseString JSONValue];
    *errorMessage = [temp valueForKey:@"errors"];

    if ([[temp valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can try setting `errorMessage` to `nil` (first line of code). Is this the line that throws the exception: `if (!errorMessage || [errorMessage isEqualToString:@""]) {`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is that `errorMessage` is not initialized and not set to a `NSString` even though `rcode` is not 0.

Try: `NSString *errorMessage - nil;` and checking to insure `errorMessage` is set in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

When, at the beginning of your method, you define - without initialization -:

```
NSString *errorMessage;
```

you're in fact defining an id which has not been set to a valid value (that is a valid string using alloc-init or simply nil) so the memory area content pointed by errorMessage is not valid, that is it can be anything: an invalid area (which will lead to EXC_BAD_ACCESS) or another area previously taken by a now dealloc'd class (like in your case: this will raise an invalid selector exception) or in the worst case an area taken by another now dealloc'd NSString (difficult to debug!). 
Later you call sendFax:phone_call_id:... method which returns rcode and has as side effect to update the errorMessage pointer by let it point to a valid address (or nil). It doesn't and then when you check errorMessage you get one of the errors above.
I suppose from your code that when rcode is set some error occurred. In such case this method must assign something to errorMessage, even a nil or an empty string, to avoid this error. So probably the sendFax: method is missing this detail.